# SQL Function issue with max and code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function

I'm trying to create a function in sql but its not working, which accepts a parameter of `@year` int, returns a data type of `money`, use the `@year` to return the amount from `Ref_table` where the `@year` falls between `begin_year` and `end_year`. if there is no value, return the amount from 
`Ref_table` with the highest `end_year` that is less than `@year`

here is my code:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_year(
    @year int 
)

RETURNS money
as
begin

declare @begin_year int
declare @end_year int
declare @amount money

select  @begin_year = begin_year,
            @end_year = end_year
from DBO.REF_Table
if @year between year(@begin_year) and year(@end_year)
    select @amount = amount
    from dbo.REF_Table
end
else if @amount is null
begin
    select @amount = amount
    from dbo.REF_Table
    where max @end_year
    and @end_year < @year
end
End
GO
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  As a hint, your `select` queries should have `where` clauses that filter the rows in the table using columns in the table.

Comment: Why `else if`?  Obviously @amount is null at that point.  Your code has syntax errors as well, `max @end_year`?  really?

Comment: I appreciate your help on this, sorry I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
select top 1 @amount = amount from myTable
where @year <= end_year
order by end_year desc
```

Comment: I believe you will need the `between` to get what he wants

Comment: I believe, he will get what he wants, cause if between record is not there then he wants max record which is less than @year.

Comment: you're right, since he's doing the else as fuzzy logic

Comment: Between will be required, if he wants to SUM all records between start_year & end_year.

Comment: There will be only one row for a set of years, non of the years will be repeated in the table

Comment: If you got desire result, always remember to mark answer as "Useful" for you any questions on StackOVerflow.